# guest chat session top guest wishlist/ call for desired speakers

Tags: discussion, chat-events

the new Physics SE guest chat sessions have gone generally well this summer (some brief [summary/ history](https://vzn1.wordpress.com/2016/08/09/daniel-sank-phd-google-quantum-computing-lab-stackexchange-physics-guest-speaker-aug-12-2016/)); we now have 3 basically successful events with talented/ qualified speakers and am personally pleased/ happy with the outcome so far which for me is mostly "better than expected" overall. it seems there was a lot of excitement initially over the project that has subsided somewhat; the ongoing/ day-to-day logistics are challenging. not sure exactly what all the initial excitement was related to, maybe partly the idea of increasing the scale/ impact to Reddit size (which is quite substantial/ formidable/ far away if ever!), however another key element of interest was *who to invite*.

we all have physics heroes we admire, working in fields of our maybe strong personal tastes/ interests. so its "really cool" to imagine them accepting invitations and showing up to this corner of cyberspace so to speak, or even better, having topnotch guests volunteer for the effort.

the basic idea for this post is as a **call for desired guests**. who would be your dream guest you would invite to our meetings and why? the built-in stackexchange voting can serve as an informal polling mechanism, and also a public indication of community interest for the targeted guests to weigh/ consider. for now, let there be no constraint on *feasibility*. this will just be a list without regard to actual feasibility or availability. its a whole other (open) question of how to encourage/ lean on/ incentivize the top desired guests.

there were some key names that popped up in the chat of people that others wanted to invite, and have been tracking them & may add them to this post later if there are no immediate objections, have many other ideas on that.

(response format: it would be nice to have separate answers/ voting for every single guest, but that could get unwieldy with a lot of responses, so am not sure which is preferred/ would work best right now, maybe others have some idea there. also note that anyone *already a member of stackexchange* may have a better chance of participating.)

Comment: I don't think there is any point in really asking about "dream guests" because most of those will be ridiculously out-of-reach...

Comment: are they alive? do they have a computer? connected to the internet? can they type? those are some of the prerequisites. of course there are many others that may get in the way, but the whole idea is to get feedback/ just make a list according to _desirability_ and nothing else, and maybe youd like to expand on what you mean by "out of reach". ps there is already at least one _physics nobel prize winner_ already active on this site.

Comment: @vzn: `are they alive?....` so are we starting to look guests outside of SE then?